# Why would you put your ClojureScript source directory in :source-paths?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript

When setting up a Clojure + ClojureScript project, most commonly, I've seen people put their Clojure source directory *and* their ClojureScript source directory on their `project.clj`'s top-level `:source-paths`. For instance, [Chestnut, a Clojure + ClojureScript template, uses](https://github.com/plexus/chestnut/blob/789dbfc9e83cd3d4f685151724ddf4548f6db7bf/src/leiningen/new/chestnut/project.clj#L7):

```
:source-paths ["src/clj" "src/cljs"]
```

I may not understand Leiningen enough, but doesn't that just put those directories on the classpath? Why would you want your ClojureScript on the classpath? I would think that pointing `cljsbuild` at it and getting it to compile would be enough.

Comment: IIRC, it makes REPL interaction between clj and cljs fns easier... hence the eventual evolution to cljx where we're compiling some of the same fns (and ns's) for both targets.

Comment: Huh. Do you know how it makes it easier? Clojure's not actually going to load any of the `.cljs` files, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will at least make the ns's available at the repl since most cljs is also valid clj... I think it might also relieve some of the issues with Austin that I'm having atm so I'm going to try it on a branch of a current project right now :)

Comment: That being said, I'm pretty sure the point of cljx was to avoid this issue entirely.

Comment: No, `.cljs` files on the classpath will not be loaded by Clojure, even if the code they contain happens to be valid Clojure (which will frequently not be the case). Neither will `.cljx` files be loaded by Clojure itself, or for that matter by ClojureScript; the `cljx` plugin for Leiningen outputs `.clj` and `.cljs` files and only those preprocessed files are then consumed by the Clojure and ClojureScript compilers, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the ClojureScript source tree to `:source-paths` is one of the simplest ways of ensuring that Leiningen includes it in jars and überjars. It is not adequate for all projects, however, and so ClojureScript libraries use all sorts of different arrangements.

- If you're implementing a pure ClojureScript library, you may find it convenient to use the `:source-paths` approach – or you could place your `.cljs` files inside the default `"src"` directory.
- If you're using `cljx`, you'll want to include the `.clj` and `.cljs` files it produces in your jars, so something like [Sente's `project.clj`](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente/blob/v1.1.0/project.clj) (link to version 1.1.0) may work better for you.
- If you don't need to include your ClojureScript source files in your jars, you're free to mention your `.cljs` files to lein-cljsbuild only.